# Get date format of actual loaded locale script

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I dynamically import the locale script to i18n my application:

```
$scope.setCountry = function(countryKey) {
        // Dynamically load i18n Angular locale depending on country select
        var imported = document.createElement('script');
        var fileImport = 'angular-locale_' + countryKey + '.js';
        console.log(fileImport);
        imported.src = 'i18n/angular-locale/' + fileImport;
        document.head.appendChild(imported);
};
```

How do I get the actual loaded date format? for e.g. the shortDate?

I need it like this:  dd/MM/y (UK for e.g.)
Thank you!

Comment: use $locale service, `$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.medium`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use $locale service and then read the date format using `$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.medium`

Comment: There is still one more issue. Even if I change the locale in AngularJS and then request for the current locale using your code snippet , it still remains to en-us. The formatting such as Currency, date, however, be changed to the new locale. Do you have any tipps?